# What is the prenthesized part of the version string in this MSBUILD reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rider

One of the projects in our sln file won't load references in project rider. Seems to be related to references as that part of the project is empty in the solution explorer. Submitting the problem to Jetbrains gives a popup for DEXP-168128.

This is the bad reference that causes the issue:

```
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.4506.8693 (QFE.030729-8600), Culture=neutral,
```

and changing it to this fixed the issue:

```
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.4506.8693, Culture=neutral,
```

What is the (QFE.030729-8600) part of the version string? That's been in our code base for 7 months. It works fine in VS, but it's also the only version string like that in our entire code base.

Comment: We'll fix it in Rider, hope even to next EAP =)

Comment: I'm very excited for the finished product. Rider has been extremely useful for cases where resharper ultimate and VS choke on certain projects that we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QFE is Quick Fix Engineering, a type of hotfix. The number is probably the issue it relates to.

There are two others you may encounter, GDR which is General Distribution and LDR which is Limited Distribution.

Comment: What are these letters are doing in the middle of the assembly textual identity, or how they should be treated when applied to the target assembly? It does not even fit the grammar. Looks like a corrupted version string to my eye. Is there any known format owner or format description?

Comment: If it is corrupted VS handles it gracefully. If anyone posts a link to the MSDN documentation for this it would be good.

Comment: Yep should skip the stuff of course and proceed. But it would be better to parse & understand. Which requires the missing bits — like, what to do with it :)
Chances not too high that it's a real format.

Answer (score 1):

QFE stands for Quick Engineering Fix. It's a hotfix for an issue.

Comment: What are these letters are doing in the middle of the assembly textual identity, or how they should be treated when applied to the target assembly? It does not even fit the grammar. Looks like a corrupted version string to my eye. Is there any known format owner or format description?

Comment: @hypersw they are a different build.

Comment: I'm looking at this from a technical point of view: this text is not an assembly name, what is it then?

Comment: @hypersw it's part of the version string

Comment: An assembly version is stored as four 16-bit integers, no freehand strings as in Nuget there. Where to look for it?